# What is the loki wallet cli command to join a staking pool service node?

Tags: monero-forks, loki, proof-of-stake, staking, loki-wallet-cli

Currently the docs only show how to do join a loki staking pool via the gui: https://docs.loki.network/ServiceNodes/GUIStakingGuide/

But how does one join a staking pool via the command line loki wallet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is actually described here: https://docs.loki.network/ServiceNodes/SNFullGuide/#622-pool-contributor

```
stake <Service Node Pubkey> <contribution amount>
```